# How to access mysql database from one server to another server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am new Ruby on Rails. I need to access mysql database of one server (For example, xxx.xxx.xx) to another server (xxx.xxx.xx) in ruby on rails. is this possible in ruby script?
Can you anybody guide me?

Comment: You mean you have a remote db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to mention host and port in your `database.yml` file.

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: databasename
  username: username
  password: password
  host: xx.xx.xx.xx
  port: 3306
```

Comment: Thanks. I need another clarification. i have rake task for importing images using remote_url with the help of paperclip plugin. created photos folder under rails project folder if i run that rake on localhost server. is it possible to put all images in the new server.

Comment: I guess it should, but am not sure. Try to figure it out from google search, if you could not found any solution ask a new question. There should be somebody who might faced the same issue and could help you out.